# Optimal control model of an articulated part that starts from station A and arrives at station B.

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling, control-theory

I have the following optimal control problem:

Formulate a model of optimal control of a joint that starts from station A and arrives at station B and you want to know how far you should start to decelerate and you also want to know the optimal time.

1. I have an articulated bus that moves in an exclusive way and part of
   stop A with initial velocity equal to zero and arrives at stop B
   with final velocity equal to zero and the speed limit on the road is $40 km / h$.
2. I am considering that the traffic lights that are in the exclusive way are in green light every time the articulated bus is near.
3. The driver of the articulated bus is interested in knowing at what distance he should stop accelerating the articulated to reach stop B with zero speed. With this we are indicating that we must control is the acceleration due to the accelerator, that is, the acceleration will be my control variable.. From here I got the following question: How to find an equation of the speed that is a function of the position ?, that is, $v = v (x)$ and also how this variable could add variables such as speed in curves, if the road has slopes, among others.
4. The maximum acceleration I think will be limited by the capacity of
   the engine and the maximum deceleration will be limited by the
   capacity of the braking system.
5. Finally, How can I formulate a cost functional that minimizes travel time?

Comment: You need to specify the constraints as otherwise the optimum is infinite speed until you reach the destination then stop.  A typical one is a limit on acceleration, which might be different between acceleration and deceleration.  Another is a limit to speed.  If  there are special speed limits at places along the way, for curves or hills, you need to say that.

Comment: @amWhy I made a first sketch of this model based on the classical theory of optimal control https://ece.gmu.edu/~gbeale/ece_620/notes_620_minimum_time.pdf But then I realized that what really should be interesting is when the accelerator should be released in order to arrive with speed and also that the speed would be a function of distance and not of time.

Comment: @RossMillikan Could you recommend books about this problem?

Comment: No, I don't know any.

Comment: @AlexPozo Please. Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818940/what-is-the-minimum-time-from-point-a-to-point-b/2851939#2851939

Comment: @Cesareo I was talking with some colleagues and dealing with this problem with a dynamic like the one shown on the link would not be feasible, since the speed of the bus is changing in each position (along the way), that is, it is a function of the position and not only as a function of time.

Comment: @AlexPozo Could you specify  the required dynamics? This knowledge is essential  in order to formulate conveniently  the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The basic equations for constant acceleration with $s$ being position, $v$ being velocity, and $a$ being acceleration are 
$$v=v_0+at\\s=s_0+v_0t+\frac 12at^2$$
with the zero subscripts representing starting values.  If you have a limiting velocity $v_{lim}$and fixed acceleration, you reach that velocity after $\frac {v_{lim}}a$ at distance $\frac 12at^2$.  That is the distance from the end you should start to decelerate at.

Comment: I think they do not understand the concerns I have. If we are driving the bus and we want to travel in the shortest possible time, the idea would be to press the accelerator thoroughly, but we have a speed limit of $40km/h$, remember that we want to reach stop B with zero speed, that is, we want to know how far we should go stop pressing the accelerator, with this I think we should have $v = v (x)$. I think that using equations of uniformly varied linear motion is not useful for this kind of problem.

Comment: Without information on other constraints, the equation for uniform motion gives the optimum.  You start from zero speed, accelerate as quickly as possible to maximum speed, then at the end decelerate as quickly as possible to reach the target with zero velocity.  You can compute the deceleration distance as$\frac 12\frac {v^2}a$ so you start decelerating that far from the end.

Comment: Can I see this problem only with a variation calculation problem? Since I could get a function $T(v)=\int_{A}^{B}\frac{dx}{v}$ where $v$ I would get it from the free-body diagram of the bus, considering that the mobile is on an inclined plane and there is a presence of friction.

Comment: That is a completely  different problem than you have been talking about.  Earlier somebody was choosing the acceleration within certain constraints.  Now you have a mechanics problem driven by gravity.  *Please* figure out what you are asking.